# Rails Update! does not raise an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

I have a transaction and in it I have the following code:

```
@schedule.update!(production_grid: true)
```

The problem is - the field is a boolean, I tried testing for failures by trying to pass in some text:

```
@schedule.update!(production_grid: "Break")
```

The record did not get updated, and an exception was not raised.  What do I need to do to raise an error if the record is not updated?

**UPDATE**

This post sums it up:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/save-bang-your-head-active-record-will-drive-you-mad

> All they do is save the object and raise an exception if any
>   validation fails.

Comment: you can inspect errors like @schedule.errors like Rails.logger.info(@your_object.errors.inspect)

Comment: Thanks - that's neat.  I just don't see what the point of the update! method is if failing an update doesn't raise an exception.  I was hoping to use this throughout a number of transactions where inspecting elements all the time would be a big pita.

Comment: it didn't raise an error because `'Break'` is a truthy value.  try adding a validation instead and make the record fail that validation.

Comment: Thanks - I just read a post where it said save! and update! only enforce validations.  You can mark that as an answer